# Unable to fetch response after login using Retrofit2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am trying to login user in my app for that I am using retrofit2 for networking But when after entering email and password my app is crashing and showing below logcat error.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference

Below is my code:

Login response is

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "email": "digi@gmail.com",
        "address": "Hsbdbshbd"
    }
],
"status": true,
"code": 200
}
```

**RetrofitClient.java**

```
public class RetrofitClient {

public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getInstance(){

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(22, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(22, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(22, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    if(retrofit == null)
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://www.gurgaonhomeo.in/api_server/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();

    return retrofit;
   }
}
```

**ApiService.java**

```
@POST("login")
@FormUrlEncoded
Observable<LoginResponse> loginUser(@Field("email") String email,
                                      @Field("password") String password);
```

**LoginResponse.java**

```
public class LoginResponse {

@Expose
@SerializedName("code")
private String code;

@Expose
@SerializedName("data")
private List<LoginRes> data;

@Expose
@SerializedName("status")
private String status;

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public List<LoginRes> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<LoginRes> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
}
```

**LoginRes.java**

```
public class LoginRes {

@SerializedName("address")
private String address;

@SerializedName("email")
private String email;

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
} 
}
```

**Login.java**

```
 private void signIn(String mail, String pwd) {

    Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
    ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

    apiService.loginUser(mail,pwd).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                  .subscribe(new Observer<LoginResponse>() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                                      }

                                      @Override
                                      public void onNext(LoginResponse loginResponse) {

                                          prg.dismiss(); 
                                          List<LoginRes> res = loginResponse.getData();
                                          Toast.makeText(Login.this, "" +res.get(0).getEmail(), 
                                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                       }

                                      @Override
                                      public void onError(Throwable e) {

                                          TastyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG,
                                                  TastyToast.ERROR).show();
                                          prg.dismiss();
                                      }

                                      @Override
                                      public void onComplete() {

                                      }
                                  });
}
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: `java.util.List.get(int)' on a null ....` Have a look at `res.get(0)`.

Comment: `I am unable to get it` Indeed.  ;-)

Comment: I am unable to get email and address.

Comment: Yes, but before that you are unable to get a list.

Comment: yeah, but why what's the problem  here in my code.

Comment: A pointer is null. And you are using a null pointer. So you got a null pointer exception.

Comment: I have updated my post please check the login response.

Comment: here is an api `http://www.gurgaonhomeo.in/api_server/login` you can check  response where `email=digi@gmail.com` and `password=digi1234`.

Comment: At the moment that is irrelevant. You should find out the variable/pointer that is null. On this null pointer you try to call .get(0). I told you that already in my first comment.

Comment: Please print   List<LoginRes> res = loginResponse.getData();

It looks like loginResponse.getData(); is null.

Comment: I suggest to use logging interceptor. it prints all requests and responses. so you can see the things better.

Comment: 1. Are you using GsonConverterFactory when initializing your retrofit? 2. Are there any logs generated when the request is processed? It could be that the Gson couldn't parse your response for some reason. If that's the case consider creating the Gson object for your GsonConverterFactory which sets the lenient property to false that allows throwing an exception when something goes wrong when the Gson tries to parse a JSON.

Comment: @MPetrychko Yes I have added GsonConvertor library along with retrofit.

Comment: @SusanMustafa its showing `null` when I am doing `List<LoginRes> res = loginResponse.getData()`

Comment: @Digvijay Try setting a custom Gson object with lenient(false) to your GsonConvertor class when initializing retrofit. This should throw exceptions when there is a parsing error.

Comment: @MPetrychko, could you plz show me the code.

Comment: @Digvijay It should look something like this: new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson()))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient);

Comment: @Digvijay By default the Gson has lenient property set to false which implies that when there are violations of json format the Gson will throw an exception. The violations are described here https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html#method.detail. So if you set lenient property to true you won't be able to see these violations because they will be ignored.

Comment: @MPetrychko I have updated my post please look at my retrofit builder.

Comment: @DigvijayYou should remove `setLenient()` in `new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()` because that actually tells Gson to ignore violations of json format. After you removed it, check if there is any error in your `onError` method.

Comment: @MPetrychko I have removed `setLinent()` but stilll showing null.

Comment: Ok, so this doesn't look like a parse error. In that case try adding logging interceptor to your okHttp client. First add this library to your `build.gradle` - `implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0")`. Then change your okHttp client initialization by adding interceptor: `OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()...
            .addNetworkInterceptor(new LoggingInterceptor())
            .build();`. This interceptor will print your request/response to the logcat. Then look at the response and see if there is a list or any other data.

Answer (score 0):

After `List<LoginRes> res = loginResponse.getData();` line check for `Log.d("TAG", "response: " +res)`
Check if the res value is null or not?
Also check here `@POST("login")` I think in this part `"login"`, there should be an url of login that will be use after base url.

Comment: I think the problem is in your api calling with specific url. Modify `"login"` with login url.

Comment: here is an url `http://www.gurgaonhomeo.in/api_server/login`.

Comment: Let me know your Android Device's version that you tested.

Comment: I am testing on android version 6(Marshmallow).

Comment: Its also not working on android version 9 showing response `null`.

Comment: Sometimes http urls are occured such type of problem. You can use `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in your manifest file. Like this

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.package">

    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />

</manifest>`